# Copying Excel sheet content to a new sheet does not copy VBA Form controls in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2013, vba

I created an Excel workbook that "generates" new forms (tabs) based on selections made in the main tab. Background: I have hidden predefined tabs that I created and based on the selections made in the main tab, my VBA code will copy contents from a specific hidden tab and paste contents to a new tab that's automatically created through VBA. The new tab that has the pasted contents also contains a form control (button).

Everything works perfectly fine in Excel 2010 and higher but in Excel 2007 the form button is missing in my pasted contents tab. I cannot find any issues with my code and cannot identify why the button is not getting copied over as well.

Code that checks to see if a sheet exits and if not then it creates a new tab and copies contents from hidden tab to the newly created tab.

What part of my code is not compatible for Excel 2007 and how do I go about fixing this issue?

```
Sub NewWorkSheetProcess(ByVal b As String)

Dim numLines As Integer
Dim requestType, clientNumber, clientName, processType, screenName, ProcessName

requestType = Sheets("FrontPage").Range("c9")
clientNumber = Sheets("FrontPage").Range("c7")
clientName = Sheets("FrontPage").Range("c5")
processType = Sheets("FrontPage").Range("c11")
screenName = Sheets("FrontPage").Range("c13")
ProcessName = Sheets("FrontPage").Range("c15")

    If Not SheetExists(b) Then

        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = b
        Sheets("MainProcess").Cells.Copy Worksheets(b).Range("A1")
        Worksheets(b).Cells(5, 3).Value = ProcessName
        Worksheets(b).Cells(7, 3).Value = clientName
        Worksheets(b).Cells(8, 3).Value = processType
        Worksheets(b).Cells(6, 3).Value = screenName
        Worksheets(b).Cells(9, 3).Value = Worksheets(b).Name

    End If
    If Worksheets(b).Name = "Modify Process" Then
        MsgBox "Please ensure to highlight/notate all required configuration changes. -Thank you!", VbMsgBoxStyle.vbInformation, "Courtesy Message"
    End If
End Sub
```

Update: I tried adding `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True` before my copy and still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```

before running the `Copy`

Comment: Thanks, I will test it out tomorrow on another machine as I dont have office 2007 installed on mine. If works I will accept your answer.

Comment: I had someone test it out on the their machine with Office 2007 and the form button still does not appear. The original code I posted seems to work only for Office 2010 and above. Any other ideas? below is the piece of code where I added:

Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
Sheets("MainProcess").Cells.Copy Worksheets(b).Range("A1")

Comment: That always worked for me in XL2007 (but I'm now on 2010 so can't test).